# pass input value with jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In my app, which is created on a single page template i have a list on page 5, which is created dynamically from a server. This works also fine. However, I want then pass a list value to the next page (page6). For this I created following code. after submit the form, the page 1 is showed instead of page 6. Is there any error in this code?

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', '#p5', function() {

    $('form').submit(function() {

        content = $('[name=content]').val();

        $.mobile.changePage("#p6");
        return false;
    });

});

$(document).on('pageinit', '#p6', function() {
    $('.ui-content').text(content);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I tried to create a file, but I does not work in jsfiidle.net Can you also check on our test server - http://app.lovanet.ch/phonegap/app/www/index.html

Comment: I'm finding it quite difficult to use your form, however, after I click to go to page 6, I do not see the behaviour you described, it appears to successfully go to the next page.

Comment: You mean in general is it difficult? we will use this for mobile only. Ah sorry the button send on page 5 on the right top corner we have to delete. The user should then use the submit buttons on the results respectively on the list items and there it doesn't work.